# SQL Logic for Isolating records that are in list One but Not List two

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

OK, I am working on developing a query that can isolate members who used a service on their account for a two week period (say 4/1 to 4/14) then compare that to a list of members who used a service for the following two week period (4/15 to 4/) and then identify who used a service in period one and then did not use a service in period two.

The query to get the week one list works fine with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
```

The query for the second week is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
```

I tried putting both of these together with a  'NOT EXISTS' clause on in both the FROM section and the where section but both have issues. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: What were the issues with the NOT EXISTS clause?   There's no reason you can't solve your problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`except`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) to return all distinct rows from the first query that are not in the second:

```
SELECT SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))

except

SELECT SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
```

---

Alternative using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and `not exists()`

```
;with cte as (
SELECT SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
)
select distinct SS.memid
FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 
                         61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from cte
    where ss.memid = cte.memid
    )
```

Comment: It says that the 'Except' construct is not supported. I am using sql 2008 with reporting services

Comment: @Merlin `except` is supported in sql server 2008. Is your server a different version? try `select @@version` -- screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/58b2e95c6c44895eb2795431c827a8be.png

Comment: EXCEPT and INTERSECT should be available to a 2008 instance. EXCEPT would definitely be the easiest to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql